# detecting file changes in folder when program is not running

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I checked that the folder that's watched by FileSystemWatcher actually does not check or tells the changes in the folder while the program is not running. How can I check the changes in the folder when the program is off? I mean, how can the program tell 'the changes in the folder when the program is off'?

Comment: Can you do the check when you application starts?

Comment: Just off the top of my head you could keep a snapshot of file details name, size, modification date etc which gets updated when the file system watcher detects a change. When the program starts up, it would scan the filesystem and then compare that to the snapshot.

Comment: I agree with @MrSlim.  Keeping a snap shot of the filenames and modified dates should suffice.  Any files that have changed will have to go through a couple of hoops to ensure the modified date hasn't changed when it has been updated. Oh, and of course any files that now exist that didn't before, will have to be included.

Comment: @MrSlim Then should I make another file to check changes in files?

Comment: Correct, you will need to store the snapshot somewhere. You can use whatever technology you have at your disposal, a file, a database etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know that the changes have happened *when they happen*, you'll need to use a service (see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications).